# Using foreground service in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-service, foreground, flutter-plugin

I am using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/foreground_service#-example-tab-)  to use forground service in a flutter app i am trying the sample app in the example of this package but i am getting error which i am not able to understand

```
 Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method foregroundServiceIsStarted on channel org.thebus.foreground_service/main)
E/flutter ( 9491): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 9491): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9491): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 9491): #2      ForegroundService._invokeMainChannel (package:foreground_service/foreground_service.dart:21:33)
E/flutter ( 9491): #3      ForegroundService.foregroundServiceIsStarted (package:foreground_service/foreground_service.dart:133:18)
E/flutter ( 9491): #4      _MyAppState._toggleForegroundServiceOnOff (package:foregroundserviceflutter/main.dart:66:50)
E/flutter ( 9491): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter ( 9491): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter ( 9491): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 9491): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter ( 9491): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter ( 9491): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:254:7)
E/flutter ( 9491): #11     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 9491): #12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter ( 9491): #13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 9491): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 9491): #15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 9491): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
```

Any suggestion on what's going wrong in this

Comment: what is the thrown exception? what do you see before `#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod`?

Comment: added the exception @pskink let me know

Comment: i have added the following plugin also

Answer (score 0):

i have added the following plugin also – @Neelay Srivastava

**MissingPluginException**

**what ever plugin you add it is not integrated in app although the plugin is get by pub
but not interacted in app for that you just have to quit app and build again**